# Dynamic Class Load file is not updating on server

Tags: database, laravel, oop, dynamic, dynamic-class-creation

When I changed something in a file containing a dynamic class who's name is called from database. its working fine for the local server, but it is not updating on the live server until I change the file name and upload it again.

could anyone what's the reason, why this happening.

Comment: Is the operating system of your local computer and server computer are same? It may cause the issue, for say Linux is case sensitive while windows is not.

Comment: In the local computer we are using windows & server computer it's on Linux operating system. but we are calling class name from database which is same for both.

Comment: It may be loading from the cash. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a write permission issue,

the file on the server must be owned by Apache.

If not then due to permission issue this can happen.

(1) Allow Apache access to the folders and the files.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data {Path}
sudo find {Path} -type d -exec chmod g+rx {} +
sudo find {Path} -type f -exec chmod g+r {} +
```